# 502 bad gateway because of permissions denied

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy django project on digitalocean using nginx and gunicorn. 
My project have the following structure

```
projects
|_isli
  |_isli
    |_forecast #project directory
      |_manage.py
      |_forecast.sock
      |_forecast
        |_wsgi.py
        |_settings.py
        |_urls.py
```

My project created inside root directory without creating additional sudo user. I know that isn't right solution but i decide so. 
In my `settings.py` file inside allowed hosts i specified ip address

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['165.22.23.233']
```

In official digitalocean docs have tutorial about deploying django using nginx and gunicorn [Deploying django using Nginx and Gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

in this article used method where gunicorn setted up as socet here is my setup `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]                                                        
Description=gunicorn daemon                                   
After=network.target


[Service]                                                     
User=root                                                   
Group=root                                                  
WorkingDirectory=/root/projects/isli/isli/forecast         
ExecStart=/root/projects/isli/env/bin/gunicorn --log-level debug --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock forecast.wsgi:application

[Install]                                                     
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after creating gunicorn.service file i run `systemctl start gunicorn` than `systemctl enable gunicorn` after it in my project directory was created forecast.sock file
Than i setup nginx in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/forecast`  with following

```
server {
    listen 165.22.23.233:80;

    location = /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}                                                                                                                       
    location / { 
          include proxy_params;                                       
          proxy_pass http://unix:/root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock;
    }
 }
```

Than `systemctl restart nginx`

When i am trying to access `http://165.22.23.233:80` from browser its promt me 502 bad gateway. After it in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file i see following

```
2020/02/09 16:29:01 [crit] 13533#13533: *11 connect() to unix:/root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock failed (
13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 178.176.218.110, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock:/", host: "165.22.23.233"
```

As i understood through this error my problem is that nginx can not access to `/root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock` file. After it i tried to check permissions to each entity of above path by

```
namei -nom /root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock
```

And here is output

```
f: /root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwx------ root root root
drwxr-xr-x root root projects
drwxr-xr-x root root isli
drwxr-xr-x root root isli
drwxr-xr-x root root forecast
srwxrwxrwx root root forecast.sock
```

In output above root user have permissions to each entity to my socket  path but why error say me that permission denied

Comment: I don't understand your project structure, is `forecast.sock` a directory with the settings.py inside it???

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry I did mistake. I just edited. Settings.py inside forecast directory

Comment: Normally nginx is running as www-data if you don't change anything. How did you change it to run as root?

Comment: @dirkgroten did you mean that I specified `User=root` inside gunicorn.service file?

Comment: No. nginx. You obviously didn’t change the defaults for nginx so it’s running as www-data. It would be easier if you also run gunicorn with the user www-data and set all the permissions for your project folder to be for www-data instead of root.

Comment: Just don’t use root for these things. Follow the instructions I’m sure digitalocean doesn’t say to use root for gunicorn.

Comment: @dirkgroten they didn'said so but I haven't any user in my Ubuntu and I build my project inside root directory as root user and to follow their instructions I need to do a lot of stuff.  But I will try to do))  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate listen from server_name:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 165.22.23.233; # (Example 192.168.0.1, example.com)
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/;
        }
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/root/projects/isli/isli/forecast/forecast.sock;
        }
}
```